# Designing my own scale with 0.01 gram resolution

Tags: power-supply, operational-amplifier, transistors, resistors, decoupling-capacitor

I'm aiming to design a weighing scale with a resolution of 0.01 grams. I'm familiar with basic electronics, but I'm not sure where to start to achieve such a high resolution. Could anyone provide guidance on the components, circuit design, and considerations necessary to achieve this level of precision? Any advice or resources would be incredibly helpful.

Comment: There's a lot more to this than just being handed component names to try. Most of the design work will have little at all to do with the electronics and far far more to do with what exactly is being weighed and in what circumstances. (This includes the range of weight to be measured, as well, of course.)

Comment: Sorry for providing less information. Am designing a continuous real time weight monitoring system for cholera patients, and i need to build a prototype so i can show it to my supervisor, but now I have managed to find a bathroom scale, when I opened inside this scale it has very simple circuit and I see that it will not help me mimic what I want to achieve in my project. I understood I need to improve alot of things inside this scale, so i want to understand electronic part for me to achieve a good resolution, because currently the bathroom scale that i found doesn't have a good resolution.

Comment: Gaining a resolution of 100 parts per trillion (ppt) isn't an easy task. Putting it mildly. I've no idea why you imagine it is about understanding and finding electronic parts. It's really about entirely different things: (A) unreasonable expectations; or (B) misguided specifications; or (C) assuming the specs are in fact truly needed then understanding enough detail to reach 100 ppt. And that last part will NOT be about some electronic part right now -- that's putting the cart before the horse. You look for parts after you figure out and prove the physics enough to say it is tenable and why.

Comment: Am new to this, your advice will greatly be appreciated. I was just told, and I've started working towards that. Please advice on what needs to be done first and I'll work towards that. Thank you

Comment: How well can you machine parts, accurately? What's the shape and dimensions of the weighing surface? How level can you make it? Where will the weight be placed on it? How consistently can you achieve that placement relative to the rest of the system? How many sensors are involved? What are their characteristics as a physicist would see it? How many orders down can you identify and then calibrate out various known unknowns? How often to measure? Etc. For anything like 100 ppt, you are into a very serious place where every physics corner must be identified and nailed down.

Comment: You probably need to worry about nearby masses, maybe even trucks driving over roads nearby (though I've not done any calcs to consider that), or working out some kind of complex "table" where you use various types of sands and gravels to damp out external vibrations. Etc. I mean, seriously. 100 ppt? It may not be impossible. (I'm as ignorant as the next person about this problem.) But I do know that unless YOU know this topic very well, you won't get there. Especially if you want to build two of these, or more, and have them match up.

Answer (score 2):

You can buy such scales at retail for $15 or $20, hardly worth building one, but in any case the electronics would be similar to that of a bathroom or kitchen scale (load cells). Popular chips include the Chinese [HX711](https://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Sensors/ForceFlex/hx711_english.pdf) or (for ~20x the price) the [AD7794](https://www.analog.com/en/products/ad7794.html).

The mechanical arrangement and sourcing a suitable load cell are non-electronic issues. You can find them from [offshore sources](https://s.click.aliexpress.com/e/_DFpcnib), for example, like the linked 100g full-scale load cell (no experience with the seller, it's just as an example, shop around for the specifications and documentation/pedigree you require).

If you are trying to get extremely high precision with a load cell that has a relatively large capacity then you  have an entire other set of problems. Noise and DC offsets due to thermal EMFs etc. for the electronics which would need to measure very low voltages, some of which is documented for the all-in-one chips, and creep and other non-ideal behavior for the load cells.

Comment: Thank you for your advice I'll definitely look into it.